# How can I make a grouped bar chart in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a grouped bar chart with 5 different variables attached to each country which would look something like this (just incase i got the name wrong);

[image]

Here is a snipet of my data and my current code using just 1 variable:

```
econ4m
Country_Name aggri_change fisheries_pdiff food_pdiff freshwater_pdiff co2_pdiff
Albania        -9.52            7.38       3.00            -1.69      6.79
Algeria        -5.13           -2.78      -1.69             1.17     -0.73
Bosnia        -8.05            2.82      -0.13            -5.22      1.95
Croatia        -2.87            5.23       0.74             1.35      2.12
Cyprus        -1.29          -28.98     -77.64            -1.19     -1.28
Egypt         9.64            3.75      -2.56            -0.94      4.13
France        -9.97           -2.04      -1.92            -1.10      0.87
Greece         2.63            0.60       0.58             0.65      0.13
```

current code

```
ggplot(econ4m, aes(x = Country_Name, y = aggri_change)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

I tried putting in another geom_line argument but it seems to just stack the bars

all data in dput format;

```
structure(list(Country_Name = c("Albania", "Algeria", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Croatia", "Cyprus", "Egypt, Arab Rep.", "France", "Greece", 
"Israel", "Italy", "Lebanon", "Libya", "Malta", "Morocco", "Slovenia", 
"Spain", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Tunisia", "Turkiye"), aggri_change = c(-9.52, 
-5.13, -8.05, -2.87, -1.29, 9.64, -9.97, 2.63, -3.08, 0.86, 6.93, 
1.16, -9.67, 4.13, -9.56, 1.03, 1.87, 5.17, -3.51), fisheries_pdiff = c(7.38, 
-2.78, 2.82, 5.23, -28.98, 3.75, -2.04, 0.6, -4.07, -3.75, -3.39, 
-3.77, 1.61, 1.25, -3.35, -2.81, -4.79, 0.4, -0.58), food_pdiff = c(3, 
-1.69, -0.13, 0.74, -77.64, -2.56, -1.92, 0.58, -2.28, 0.02, 
-1.36, -1.54, 4.57, -21.98, -0.71, -2.9, -6.34, -5.01, -0.23), 
    freshwater_pdiff = c(-1.69, 1.17, -5.22, 1.35, -1.19, -0.94, 
    -1.1, 0.65, -3.76, -1.66, -1.78, -0.11, 1.01, -1.97, 1.71, 
    -1.25, -0.94, 0.46, 1.07), co2_pdiff = c(6.79, -0.73, 1.95, 
    2.12, -1.28, 4.13, 0.87, 0.13, 0.71, -1.72, -0.02, -2.84, 
    -0.55, 5.15, -0.21, -0.42, -0.19, 3.3, 2.17)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try to share your data with `dput`, it makes easier to others to reproduce your scenario

Comment: @ViníciusFélix Sure, should be added to the bottom now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing is to get the data into 'long' format, after that it's about manipulating `ggplot` functions and arguments to make it look the way you want.
I've assumed your dataset is called `df1`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df1 |> 
  pivot_longer(-Country_Name) |> 
  ggplot(aes(Country_Name, value, fill = name))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  labs(x = "Country",
       fill = "Variable")+ 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Unstated (as yet), but depending on the need, this can also be done by swapping `name` and `Country_Name`, where the legend would show the country names instead of the pdiffs.

Comment: Too true! Nice point. I've made an assumption that by using term category in the question that the variables rather than the countries were to be dodged.

Comment: Maybe: `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-30, 30))`?